# Addresses, Times, Days of Week in Database and Domain Objects

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database-design

I am mapping out a very small database and have some design questions about good design practice. Let's say I have a *Restaurant* table, and a restaurant has an *Address* and an *Open Time* and a *Special Day* (MTuWThF)

1. A restaurant will only have one address. I'm tempted to put all
   the associated address fields (Street 1, Street 2, City, State, ZIP)
   into the *Restaurant* table, but I think breaking it out into its
   own table will allow me to create an *Address* class within my
   domain objects and, if I want to change the way Addresses are done
   later it may make it easier. I've typically thought of 1:1 tables as
   bad practice...
2. An *Open Time* is an HH:MM representation of when a restaurant opens. I don't need a full DateTime because the Date portion would be wasted. Is a varchar the best way to represent this, then?
3. There is a *Special Day* (Monday, Tuesday, etc...) I want to store in my schema as well. Does it make sense to just store this day as a varchar or would anyone recommend creating a reference table (kinda like an enum) with Sunday (1), Monday (2)...etc. and use an int to store which day the *Special Day* falls on?

   ```
   **DayOfWeek**
   Id (int)
   Day (varchar)

   **Service**
   Id (int)
   RestaurantId (int)
   DayOfWeekId (int)
   ...
   ```

Thanks guys!

Comment: To clarify, I am targeting a MS SQL Server database right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of what you're asking boils down to how you think it would work best for your needs.  Hopefully some of what I say below will be useful.

One-to-one tables aren't necessarily bad, and in fact, they're sometimes used to partition data to make retrieval more efficient.  For example, if there are 10 fields that you use a lot and 25 more that are relatively large that you don't use as much, you can put the 25 in another one-to-one table so that the database engine doesn't have to futz around with them when you're snagging the 10 fields you use all the time.

In your case, I could go either way.  Unless you're an experienced developer, I'd suggest just putting the address fields into the restaurant table.  You don't want to overthink it.  Trying to get too fancy will likely only cause you to waste a lot of time and effort on something that might never happen.  Besides, if you do decide to change the data in your address table later, honestly, just running a few ALTER TABLE commands is not going to be any easier on an address table versus just running them directly on your restaurant table.  In short, keep it simple unless you *know* that you're going to be changing it later.

Regarding times, some database systems actually support a TIME type (with a date).  For example, here is [MySQL's documentation on it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html).  Another option is to just use a standard DATETIME, but with a specific date as a reference point.  For example, January 1 1970.  So if you want to store 3:30pm, store it as '1970-01-01 15:30:00'.  You can perform whatever formatting on the back end that you want to display just the time part.  One of the advantages of this is that if you want to eventually use those times in any kind of calculation, it's *much* easier having them stored as DATETIMEs than as VARCHARs.  For example, if you want to know how long a restaurant is open on a particular day, you can use something like:

```
SELECT `closetime` - `opentime` AS "openhours" FROM `restaurants`;
```

As for storing a day of the week, honestly I'd just make it a TINYINT and store 1 (Sunday) through 7 (Saturday).  MySQL has built-in functions that return 1 through 7 as a day of week, and I think most databases are the same on that.  It would make it much easier in queries such as the one below to determine if a given date is a "special" day:

```
SELECT * FROM `restaurants` where DAYOFWEEK(?) = `special_day`
```

Most scripting languages would let you compile that as a prepared query and then you could just pipe dates in very efficiently.

Hopefully this helps and gives you some considerations.  Good luck with your project, dates and times can get really hairy to deal with, especially when you start getting into timespans and such.

Comment: Good thoughts. I am surprised no one else has any thoughts on this issue. I know it's subjective and dependent on the specific project, but its still pretty surprising to me. I think I'll piggy-back the address information on the Restaurant table and use an integer with a backing table for the day. SQL Server supports a TIME type, so Ill also probably use that.

Answer (score 0):

> I am mapping out a very small database

So it's likely the entirety of your database will fit into cache, so there will be very little reason to vertically split the table just for the better I/O - there won't be I/O to speak of.

> 1...

Databases should care about data, not how it is represented in your client application's code. I'm sure you'll be able to work with address in acceptable way in your code, even if it is not in the separate table. At the very least, you can always manually wrap whatever your ORM generated (or not use ORM in the first place ;) ).

> 2...

Well, there are 24 * 60 = 1440 minutes in a day, which will fit comfortably in a `smallint`.

If you want to query on hours only (or minutes only), keep them separate in two `tinyint` fields.

> 3...

Use a separate table and referential integrity. This way, you can change which day is special in one place and it will automatically "propagate" to all connected rows. And you can have multiple special day if you ever need to.

OTOH, if you *know* you'll always have exactly one special day, then you can create a "singleton" table with one row containing just that day. You won't really need any FKs in this case - since the number of days is small (7), it is within realm of practicality to limit valid values through CHECK constraints alone.